# Insert and update 4 million records everyday

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, bulkinsert

Auditing purpose, I want to insert 1 million records into one table

and again 1 million record into another table.

and update 1 million record in transaction table(production DB) and also again

update 1 million record in another transaction table(production DB).

so over all 40M records. I am getting error ORA-00060 deadlock detected while waiting for resource.

actually I cant give commit in between the transaction. after completed the task successfully I have to commit the transaction. like example if I keep commit for each insert, any error occurs i cant rollback.

I am new to oracle. Kindly advice.

Thanks in advance

Flow

insert 1M

insert 1M

update 1M

update 1M

commit;

```
Create or replace procedure prc_tagbalance
As
Begin
  Insert into t1 
  Select custid,mobileno,openingbal,currentvalue
  From mas_walletinfo;
Exception
  -- Error table insert using procedurr with pragma Autonomous transaction
  Return;
End;

Begin
  Insert into t2
    Select vechileid,tid,tbalance from mas_vehicleinfo;
Exception
  --error table insert
  Return;
End;

Begin
  Update mas_walletinfo set openingbal=currentvalue;
Exception
  Return;
End;
Begin
  Update mas_vechileinfo set openingbal=tbalnce:
  Commit;
Exception
  Return;
End:
End;
```

Comment: ORA-0600 has nothing to do with the number of records you are inserting.  You will have to post a [mcve] of code, otherwise, nobody here can help. Take a look [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00060_deadlock_detected_while_waiting_for_resource.htm) for some suggestions.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the inconvenience. Still its not clear. I will add full code.  Kkndy advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask your DBA - an ORA-0600 generates a trace file on the server with the details of why the system detected a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

**put commit after each operation.**

```
Create or replace procedure prc_tagbalance
As
Begin
  Insert into t1 
  Select custid,mobileno,openingbal,currentvalue
  From mas_walletinfo;
 Commit;
Exception
  -- Error table insert using procedurr with pragma Autonomous transaction
  Return;
End;

Begin
  Insert into t2
    Select vechileid,tid,tbalance from mas_vehicleinfo;
 Commit;
Exception
  --error table insert
  Return;
End;

Begin
  Update mas_walletinfo set openingbal=currentvalue;
 Commit;
Exception
  Return;
End;
Begin
  Update mas_vechileinfo set openingbal=tbalnce:
  Commit;
Exception
  Return;
End:
End;
```

Comment: Actualy if I put any commit inbetween any transaction, if any error occures. I have to roll back.